# Jenkins Declarative Pipeline throws NullPointerException when I use withCredentials

Tags: git, jenkins

I have a small pipeline that performs some GIT actions. I'm trying to use ssh as the protocol to communicate, so I defined the private key in the JenkinsServer and I have everything working fine.

```
    stage('Some Stage'){
      steps{
        withCredentials([[$class: 'SSHUserPrivateKeyBinding', credentialsId: "${params.credentialsId}", usernameVariable: 'GIT_USERNAME']]){
          script{
           // Do some git operations...
          }
       }
  }
```

If I remove the withCredentials from here the code works as fine, but I have to set the username hard coded in the git push commands. I want to fetch the username from the credentials instead. but my jenkins always throws a NPE without any other message.

I'm totally lost in this

Answer (score 2):

I also ran into this and finally realized that, to avoid the NPE, you have to include the keyFileVariable even if you're not using it.  This is needed since the username and passphrase are optional.  This will work.

```
withCredentials([[$class: 'SSHUserPrivateKeyBinding', credentialsId: cred_id, keyFileVariable: 'KEY_FILE', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME']]) {
   username = USERNAME
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below and see if it helps. You can then refer username from credentials using `GIT_CREDENTIALS_USR` and password using `GIT_CREDENTIALS_PSW`

```
stage('Some Stage'){

      environment {
                GIT_CREDENTIALS = credentials('<credentialsID>')
      }
      steps{
         script{
           // Do some git operations...
        }
    }
}
```